# Why does this throw a InputMismatchException?

Tags: java, int, mismatch

```
public class Test
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException
    {
        Scanner input = new Scanner("text.txt");
        int x = input.nextInt();        
    }
}
```

text.txt being:

```
8 
8
6  
7
```

This code throws a `InputMismatch` Exception. Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is because `"text.txt"` is not a number. Try:

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(new File("text.txt"));
```

Comment: I think you mean "file". :)

Comment: No :) I really meant number. I should have said: *`text.txt` is a String which does not contain a number.*

Answer (score 1):

The constructor [`Scanner(String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#Scanner%28java.lang.String%29) accepts a String to read from, not a file name.

So, `nextInt()` is trying to read an `int` from the String you pass to it, ie. `"text.txt"`.

Instead, use the constructor that accepts a `File` source, [`Scanner(File)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#Scanner%28java.io.File%29).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is due to overloading. You are calling new Scanner(String) instead of new Scanner(File). If you tried scanner.next() you would see it returns "text.txt"